# If I buff an infect card, is the new damage infect as well?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Let's say I have [Rogue's Passage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRogue%27s%5d%2b%5bPassage%5d) and [Phyrexian Hydra](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPhyrexian%20Hydra%5d) and I use Rogue's Passage's ability to make Phyrexian Hydra unblockable.  Then, after no spells are played that effect Phyrexian Hydra, I play [Titanic Growth](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTitanic%20Growth%5d) on the Phyrexian Hydra. Does the 11 infect kill the opponent that I am attacking as long as no other spells are cast?

Comment: Damage has many effects: addition of marked damage, addition of -1/-1 counters, addition of poison counters, loss of loyalty counters, life loss, life gain, a combinations of these, or nothing at all. Whatever the effect, the amount of it is equal to the attacking creature's power.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, your opponent is dead. As you can see from the description of Infect on the card,

> (This creature deals damage to creatures in the form of -1/-1 counters and to players in the form of poison counters.)

Like with every other creature, it deals damage equal to its power. Its power is 11, so it does 11 damage. The infect keyword means you do damage in the form of poison counters, so your opponent gets 11 poison counters and loses the game. Infect doesn't say you do poison damage equal to the printed power and the rest in normal damage; it converts all the damage to poison damage.

(There are exceptions to some of these blanket statements of course, e.g. if opponent has [Melira, Sylvok Outcast](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMelira%2c%20Sylvok%20Outcast%5d) then he doesn't get poison counters [although he takes normal damage since Melira's effect removes infect], but these exceptions would be printed on the card.)

Comment: Melira's last ability takes away infect, so they take life loss instead. She would be even more of an infect hoser if she lacked that, as the damage would be entirely negated.

Comment: Thanks I was playing a game and won like this but I was a little concerned it wasn't legal.

Comment: allure i totally support you! https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/40761/why-is-there-a-1-e4-2-ke2-bongcloud-but-not-1-d4-2-kd2-or-1-f4-2-kf2 btw pls help here https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2100/improving-question-on-championship-privilege